# convert excel colums in nested arrays/ list using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in csv file and i need to convert the data into as lists and arrays to json format. here is  a sample data:

[image]

the desired output id :

```
{
   "topics":[
      {
         "topicID":1,
             "labels":[
            {
               "phrase":"security level",
               "prob":0.3
            },
            {
               "phrase":" hack",
               "prob":0.3
            },
            {
               "phrase":"our server lab",
               "prob":0.2
            },
            {
               "phrase":" people",
               "prob":0.2
            },
            {
               "phrase":" trouble",
               "prob":0.2
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "topicID":2,
          "labels":[
            {
               "phrase":"base3",
               "prob":0.4806
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and so on.

i have just extracted 5 colums to get topics array:

`df.loc[:, ['t_1', 't_2', 't_3','t_4','t_5']]`

and i have converted topics columns to array:

```html
topic_list = df[[''t_1', 't_2', 't_3','t_4','t_5'']].values
```

but I am clueless how to append phrases and other columns in this array?

Comment: Your desired output is confusing. Do you want each column in your csv file to be an array or a dictionary?

Comment: i need weight and noun_phrases in topics array.

Comment: Can you provide a sample which shows the values of `strength` and `phrase`?

Comment: The problem is that you only provided 1 sample of data which is insufficient based on your required outputs. Where are the values `"SCORE":68` or `"strength":7`?

Comment: I have update the desired output and sample data? can you help how to iterate through columns  so i have an array of topics and text as sperate array grouped by speaker's name?